# rails 3 search between multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to avoid some gems so I came up with this solution to search between multiple models.

But It seem to just work for first model that is listed.

**SearchController** :

```
def index
    @products = Product.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    @manufacturer_name = Manufacturer.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    @category_name = Category.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

**Inside my 3 models I have like this:**

```
def self.search(search)  
    if search  
      where('name LIKE ? ', "%#{search}%") 
    else  

    scoped  
    end
```

Search#index

```
    <%if @products.present?%>
        <%= render partial: "products/found" %>
    <%end%>

  <%if @manufacturer_name.present?%>
        <%= render partial: "products/foundmanufacturers" %>
    <%end%>

  <%if @category_name.present?%>
        <%= render partial: "products/foundmanufacturers" %>
    <%end%>
```

I prepared for each model seperated partial.

But when I search for name that definetely should be in all categories. But there is no results found, only when I run search for products name. Then I get results I want.

Any tip would be great. Tnx

Comment: searching in products which has name in product or category name then return products?

Comment: @Amar I have this search enabled in three models. Prodcut, category,manufacturer. All of these have field- name. Search for all these starts in one search form. Check this : http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/ type "pez" it will return product names, then "CMI" should return manufacturer names but doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

it's just refactoring  create name scope like as shown below

```
 scope :by_name,lambda{|name| where("name like (?)","%#{name}%") if name.present?}
 # In controller
 Product.by_name(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
```

no need of `search` method in model it's better to write scope unless you are doing some complex checking,

Second try to see in console wether you are getting results based on your search params?

Comment: Tnx, First line I should add in model ?